# Bottom-left cell position is incorrect?

Tags: unity, tilemap, coordinates, position

I need to get the position of the bottom-left cell on my tilemap. I used `Floor.CellToWorld(Floor.cellBounds.min)` (Floor is the name of my tilemap) and I used Gizmos to see if it was working but it turned out to be in a weird place, the Rect Tool Also shows a wrong rect. Here's the image so I can explain better:

[image: Rect and Cell Position]

As you can see the yellow-ish part is the bottom-left part of my tilemap, the green circle (which is a wired sphere) is `Floor.CellToWorld(Floor.cellBounds.min)`, and those two thick white lines are shown by using the Rect Tool. So judging by this info, I think it's not a programming-related issue. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

The root cause is that removing the tiles doesn't actually make the `cellBounds` shrink.

For the reason of saving memory resources, the memory allocation of tilemap is progressive, only when a tile is used for the first time, cellBounds will expand to include this tile. When the tile is deleted with the eraser, cellBounds will not shrink (avoid frequent application/reclaim memory). Unity provides a button to manually reset cellBounds named `Compress Tilemap Bounds`.

Comment: Thanks! That solved the problem, is there a way to do this from script though?

Comment: You can use [Tilemap.CompressBounds](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Tilemaps.Tilemap.CompressBounds.html).

Comment: Thanks again 